# Creating expression using arcpy.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Example:
On the basis of the table which is not defined by the number of columns and rows, you need to evaluate expressions as shown, using the arcpy.SearchCursor ....

[image]

First, create a list of fields, using the arcpy.ListFields
Then, using SearchCursor needs to calculate the defined an expression, for each column separately ...

I should be to existing code insert defined an expression....

```
 values = [] # store the sum values here.
 fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "*")

 # get the OID/FID field name to skip
 desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
 if desc.hasOID:
     OIDname = desc.OIDFieldName.upper()
 else:
     OIDname = ""

 for field in fields:
     if field.name.upper() != OIDname: # skip the OID/FID field.
         if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single"):
             # sum each suitable field, but not the NULL ones - they would be bad
             with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field.name,field.name + " is not NULL") as sCur:
                 thisValue = 0
                 for row in sCur:
                     thisValue += row[0]
                 values.append(thisValue) # this will be the inserted row
             fieldNameList.append(field.name) 

 with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, fieldNameList) as cur:
     cur.insertRow(values)
```

@Michael Miles-Stimson provided the preceding code.

Instead of the sum of the "thisValue" to create a new expression?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use the [right tool for the purpose](https://www.openoffice.org/download/)

Comment: Could you please clarify this question?  As it stands, this is difficult to interpret.  It would be helpful to define your variables too.

Comment: The more complex math that you want to do isn't really GIS related, it's just python (manipulating/storing variables)

Comment: im using arcpy for calculation spatial index. Is't GIS?

Comment: Especially when you get into python scripting, there are a lot of issues which could be better answered by Python experts than by GIS experts (even though there's some overlap) -- so really StackOverflow is a better fit and more likely to get you the solution you need :)

Comment: I solved the problem .. Will you allow to ask a solution?